# Search in Splunk in a lookup table with multivalue fields

Tags: splunk

I have a lookup table that looks like below:

[image]

So I have a Splunk query that generates a table with IP addresses and I want to automatically populate the relevant DNS names.

I use the following but it does not work:

```
Index=servers signature_id=4624
| stats count by IpAddress
**| lookup lookup.csv "ip" AS IpAddress OUTPUT "dns" AS server_name**
| stats count by server_name IpAddress
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Maybe I need to make something like that before the lookup

```
| makemv delim="|" ip | mvexpand ip  | fields ip dns ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Splunk lookups use exact, wildcard, or CIDR matching, but they can't pick one of several values.  The default is exact, which means the data must precisely match a value in the specified lookup column.  In your example, the 'ip' field would have to be "ip1|ip2|ip3" to return "server1".

Wildcard matching refers to having "*" in the lookup file.  It would allow "ip" to match "subnet1*", for example.

CIDR matching allows for CIDR strings in the lookup file, which lets "ip" match "ip1/24", for example.

Both wildcard and CIDR matching must be configured in your lookup definition.  See Settings->Lookups->Lookup definitions.

Consider restructuring your lookup file to have a single IP address per line.

```
dns        ip
server1    ip1
server1    ip2
server1    ip3
server2    ip4
server2    ip5
```

This will work with your existing query.  However, looking up a dns field will only return the first IP address for that server.